# Analyze pixel color distribution by sampling image over a defined area size (or grid?)

Tags: image-processing, color

> Blockquote

I have an image of different colored particles (red, green, and yellow) that are all mixed up against a black background. I am interested in knowing what color each particle has for its neighbor (if any). Because some particles severely overlap and merge into large blobs, I cannot easily define particles with segmentation analysis. But this is okay, I am more interested in looking at neighbors by color, not by individual particle. Specifically, I want to ask what is the distribution of colors that any given color is touching (i.e. not separated by black pixels).

For analysis, rather than defining specific areas of interest, I was thinking about using a grid approach that would sample the whole image.  First, overlay a grid onto the image, with each unit of the grid approximating the size of a particle. Then I would like to have a way so that each grid can report what % of color is in the area of each grid unit. In the end, I would get a distribution for what colors are in each grid unit. Each grid could then be compiled for analysis.

So far, I have separated the channels, binarized the channel, and then pseudo colored back the original color so that everything is equal in terms of intensity. But I need some help to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Unfortunately due to unexpected server maintenance my stored images are not accessible at this moment. I've mocked up an image that should suffice.
[![mock up test image][1]][1]

```
ImageParition[image,{20}]//Grid
```

This will partition the image into the approximate size of one particle.

Perhaps the pixel colors for each square's border can be defined into a matrix that will produce a quantitative distribution for the image?

----update jun 7----

After Wjx's helpful responses and trying out more things, I would like to rephrase and simplify my question.

After the ImagePartition step, I would like to assess each square to know how many colors are in each individual square.  As Wjx mentioned earlier, the DominantColors function could be used.  For example, taking one square from my mock up partition that has red, green, and yellow (with no black background) and applying the DominantColors function yields Red, Green, and Yellow. Doing the same for one square with just green and black background yields Green and Black.

I have decided that this type of information is sufficient for my needs. So, instead of the neighbor-correlation approach, what I'd like to do is have each square of the partitioned image be analyzed with the DominantColors function.

Then, I'd like to classify each individual square based on its DominantColor result so that each square can be binned into a category. The final result for the image would then be # of squares in each category so that a distribution could be produced.

The Categories would be as follows:

1. "Negatives" - All black
2. "Red" - All red (as well as any that are red AND black)
3. "Green" - All green (as well as any that are green AND black)
4. "Mixed" - any combination of the 3 colors (i.e. R+G, R+Y, G+Y, R+G+Y+, and again, of course black is allowed in any of the combinations also since it is the background).

Hopefully this is a clearer question and should be straightforward code wise. But I still need help putting all the code together.  thank you!

-------Update Jun 9--------

@shrx - here is my code for my "pre-processing" of the colors.

Raw image:

[![Raw_Image][3]][3]

Code:

```
i= image
imgR = ColorSeparate[i, "R"];
imgG = ColorSeparate[i, "G"];

imgRB = Binarize[imgR];
imgRc = ColorReplace[imgRB, White -> Red];

imgGB = Binarize[imgG];
imgGc = ColorReplace[imgGB, White -> Green];

ImageAdd[imgRc, imgGc]
```

final output image (cannot post because I am at limit for links since I am new)

Comment: How about using ImagePartition and compare the average intensity value in the same small picture, but in different color channel. The color with greatest average intensity could be defined as the 'color of this grid unit'. Do you think this method can help? If it do help, I'll write the code and post it as an full answer

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think that could help, but I suppose it depends on what size the grid unit is, but I expected that I'd need to play around with that to figure out what would work best anyways. My main concern is being able to tell which colors are "touching" within any given square. Is there a way to use ImageParition to determine the color of each small square's neighbor post partitioning?  thank you!

Comment: I suppose using a lot of Rotate*** will do this work. It's not a hard work to associate one point in a matrix with its neighbours.

Comment: Also, there's a way to single out each particle directly by first skrinking all the particles by list manipulation then enlarge them again. The skrinking process can seperate different particles while the enlarging process restore them to their original size while keeping each particle seperated. then by checking the cross area of each pair of particles we can find all the neighbour in a more precise way.    Do you think this method will help you better and yield better results? This method can deal with particles sticking together. Can you post the processing image on?

Comment: That sounds like it could work better. Could the shrinking/particle separation work even with images that have been color separated and then binarized? I will try to post a good image tomorrow.

Comment: It's okay as long as the color separation is done properly~I mean the color is fully seperated, so one particle can only appear in one channel.

Comment: I've updated a mock image (real images are not accessible at the movement). I should sy that the Yellow color actually indicates overlap of a red and green particle. It is not a separate channel. I would be interested to see what the particle shrinking process will yield.  Perhaps another way is to look at what pixel colors each square has for its 4 sides. For example, many will have all sides black.  Some will have 80% and 20% green, others will have 25% green and 75% black, etc etc... This type of analysis would be useful as well.  Thanks

Comment: Well, if on the image those disks are such closely packed, I suppose the second method cannot do its job. The second method can only distinguish particles if they're only overlapping a bit (5% or less) and leave enough white space for detection, for example, while processing packing problems. I will post the solution of the first method.

Comment: Yes, the particle detection will be difficult due to the closely packed particles. Looking forward to trying your solution and see how it works. Thank you!

Comment: Apologizes for the extended discussion. I was just looking at the grid image again and realized that since the grid captures most intersections or intermixing of colors, perhaps the easier thing to do would be report how many squares have one individual color  (red, green, or red+black, and green+black, since black = edge, it doesn't count as interfacing with another color). And then how many squares have mixed colors (any combination of red, green, yellow).  Not sure if that's what you meant as the first method.

Comment: After your help and thinking more about the problem, I have updated my question. Please see update in post. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my approach which returns each color component's percentage in a given bin.

First, some preprocessing. This quantizes the colors using the `Nearest` function because by default Mathematica's `ColorQuantize` fails to properly quantize the image.

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/otAao.jpg"];
ncolors = 4;
dc = DominantColors[i, ncolors];
dcl = dc /. RGBColor -> List;
ndcl = Nearest[dcl];
iqdn = Map[ndcl, ImageData[i], {2}][[All, All, 1]];
```

Then, we calculate the percentage of each color in each bin with the desired bin size.

```
bin = 4;
comppart = ArrayComponents[#, 3, Thread[dcl -> Range[ncolors]]] & /@ 
   Partition[iqdn, {bin, bin}, bin];
tally = Map[Table[{n, Count[Flatten[#], n]/bin^2.}, {n, ncolors}] &, comppart, {2}];
percentages = tally[[All, All, #, 2]] & /@ Range[ncolors];
```

The percentages are returned as arrays. You can visualize them as corresponding intensity masks:

```
masks = Image[#, ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[i]] & /@ percentages;
Grid[{dc, Show[#, ImageSize -> 150] & /@ masks}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update**

As per your updated question, here's how to calculate the distribution of color categories (I have also added the `"Yellow"` category):

```
categories = # /. {
     {{1, 1.}, __} -> "Negative",
     {_, _, {3, 0.}, {4, 0.}} -> "Red",
     {_, {2, 0.}, _, {4, 0.}} -> "Green",
     {_, {2, 0.}, {3, 0.}, _} -> "Yellow",
     _ -> "Mixed"
     } & /@ Flatten[tally, 1];
counts = Reverse@Sort@N@Counts[categories]/Times @@ Dimensions[tally][[;; 2]]
```

> ```
> <|"Negative" -> 0.892626, "Red" -> 0.047619, "Green" -> 0.036268,
> "Mixed" -> 0.0158269, "Yellow" -> 0.00765965|>
> ```

Ignoring the `"Negatives"`:

```
countsNoBG = KeyDrop[counts, "Negative"]/(1 - counts["Negative"])
```

> ```
> <|"Red" -> 0.443489, "Green" -> 0.337774, "Mixed" -> 0.1474, "Yellow" -> 0.0713365|>
> ```

Compare to the sums of `percentages` (which does not know about the `"Mixed"` category):

```
(Total[Flatten[#, 1]] & /@ percentages)/Times @@ Dimensions[tally][[;; 2]]
```

> ```
> {0.910086, 0.0436594, 0.0356883, 0.0105666}
> ```

Comment: this looks great! I will play around with it and see if I have any questions. thank you

Comment: This looks very promising. thank you! I tried it out with more mock images to see how it responded to images with vary amount of mixing.  I have a few questions.  (1) What area size does it sample the image? It doesn't look like you used an image partition and I cannot figure out which part of the code is instructing this. (2) I would like to leave out the "negative" category in the percentage response. So that only area with colors gets reported in the percent distribute.

Comment: (con'td) (3) In trying different mock up tests, your code detected higher levels of mixing when particles were really mixed up, but not consistent with lower levels. For example, if I have no mixing (all separate Red and Green) it still reported mixing at 0.02. If I had some mixing (imaging a bunch of red that form a continuos boundary with green) it should be slightly higher mixing because any area samples along the border will have some red and green. But the mixing was not increased (even when normalized to % negative)

Comment: (cont'd) (4) if there is no yellow, it still reports a positive non-zero number for yellow. this is also true if everything is green or red, it will report high level of the other color but nothing for that color. (5) if there is no mixing (i.e. no non-like colors are touching) it still reports a positive non-zero for mixing.

Comment: 1) It uses 4x4 bin sizes. You change the bin size by modifying the `bin` variable. 4) This code assumes there are 4 dominant colors (R, G, Y and B). If there are more or less color blobs, it should be changed accordingly. I will edit the code so you can specify the number of colors.

Comment: @Nathur I have added the `ncolors` variable to specify the number of dominant colors. The code for `categories` can't be easily adapted, though.

Comment: 2) I have added an example that calculates the percentages only for blob colors, ignoring the black background.

Comment: great, really appreciate your help. I will try this out again. if I want to check the bin variable unit on the original image, would it be appropriate to use ImageParition[image,{bin}]//Grid?

Comment: I think it looks quite good! a few more questions- (1) if i take an image with only 3 colors (R, G, black) that has no mixing (each color only mixes with itself or black), and set ncolors =3, it masks correctly but shows Mixed->1.  Shouldn't it show Green -> 1.0? (2) just to make sure the interpretation of the outcome = what the code is doing is correct in my mind.  any countNoBG value indicates whether or not, when binned at bin size n, the contents of that bin are green, red, mixed, or all yellow? Does your mixed bin include yellow?

Comment: (3) also, the values given for Red and Green bins seemed to be reversed from what you'd guess from the image and looking at the mask display. If you reverse the order in the categories line it then looks correct

Comment: Do you understand how the `categories` code works (the replacement rules)? This is where the categories are manually set and this is what I was talking about earlier when I said this should be manually changed for a different number of colors.

Comment: not fully, I am a just starting with mathematica. But I am assuming that the values assigned to each category come from the RGBColor classifying scheme?

Comment: Yes, for example `{{1, 1.}, __}` is a pattern that matches all entries where the first color (black) occupies 100% of the bin. Similarly, `{_, _, {3, 0.}, {4, 0.}}` is a pattern that matches all entries where the 3rd an 4th colors are not present in the bin (0% occupancy).

Comment: great, i am starting to learn, thank you. so for mixed, "_" assigns what exactly? anything that's not specified previously?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html Indeed it matches every element that was not matched before.

Comment: got it, thank you.  Final question for tonight - I am now trying to apply the code to real images. Previously, I have been taking the following steps to "quantize" the images: ColorSeparate, Binarize each channel, then ColorReplace back to original color, and then ImageAdd to recombine.  When I use the products of this method in your code, it works like the mock up images (the mask print shows Red, Green, Yellow). If I use my raw images through your code, it detects Red, Green, and and lighter green. The % values differ greatly. any ideas?

Comment: in the words, whats the functional difference between my pre-processing steps and yours?

Comment: Please provide one of your raw images that doesn't work. What exactly are your preprocessing steps (code)?

Comment: i've posted my code and an example of a raw image. i cannot post the final output since I am that the limit of links.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few steps in solving this problem:

1. Separate colors completely
2. Partition the image
3. Compute the correlation between neighbouring picture segments.

To solve the first problem, I use `ColorQuantize` first in order to make similar colors the same to avoid noise. Then by using `LinearSolve`, I can change the three colors to R/G/B so that I can use `ColorSeparation` conveniently.

Then, I use `ImagePartition` to split this picture into parts.

Finally, I use `RotateRight` and `Thread` to make connection between neighbouring image segments.

The final, and the most important, step is defining and calculating the 'connection index'. So if a image segment with 70% of color A and 30% of color B is adjacent with another with 30% of A and 50% of C, We will assume that there're a 70%*50%=35% connection between A and C for this two adjacent segment. Obviously, if you put a image segment purely in color A and another purely in color C together, this index will be 100%, indicating that one A particle is adjacent to C, sounds reasonable.

The solution will come out after you sum up all the indexes.

The code is as follows:(Maybe not that elegantly written, but still fulfills the goal)

```
img = ColorQuantize[(*put your image here*), 10];
colors = Rest@DominantColors[img, 4];
restore[{r_, g_, b_}] = LinearSolve[Transpose[List @@@ colors]
   , {r, g, b}];

arr = (Clip[
      Map[Mean@*Flatten@*ImageData /@ ColorSeparate[#] &, 
         ImagePartition[Image@Map[restore, ImageData@img, {2}], 
          20], {2}]*2 - 1] + 1)/2;

mat = Total@
   Flatten[Apply[Outer[Times, #1, #2] &, 
     Thread /@ 
      Thread[{arr, 
        RotateRight[arr, {1, 0}] + RotateRight[arr, {0, 1}]}], {2}], 
    1];

Prepend[Transpose@Prepend[mat + Transpose@mat, colors], {""}~Join~
   colors] // MatrixForm
```

I hope this post can solve your problem~:)

---

Some further explanation: 
The method I gave in the comment area can yield better result when dealing with this form of pictures:
[image: A Sample Picture]
Usually this method will apply better in 3D situations and when the spacing between particles are larger because it will need the gap between particles to distinguish different particles.
So it seems that in your situation, the result of this method will not be satisfying. sorry~

Comment: thank you! I will try this and see how it works.  Do you also know of a way that could just report the colors in each grid? Not dominant color, but all of the colors?

Comment: So this works very well for the example! Just to be clear, the matrix reports the summed percent of the image of all the individual squares that have a color and neighbor another color in each direction, correct?  It tends to not work as well when you try more complicated mock ups. I'm thinking that it would be safer to try an approach such as my comment above.

Comment: Fortunately, the thing you need is all included in the matrix arr~:) As you can see, at level 2 of arr, each element is in the form {r,g,b}. so for example, {0.3,0.4,0} just symbolize 30% of this image is covered by color 1, 40% are covered by color 2 and there's no color 3. But the drawback of this solution is that it can only deal with picture with 3 dominant color(black is not included~)

Comment: but the total area covered does not indicate how they are arranged. in other words, one image could have 0.5 red and 0.5 green that has all red on one half and all green on the other half. A different image could have 0.5 red and 0.5 red but be completely mixed up randomly. This would be different particle behaviors but have the same values. that's why i'm focusing on the squares.  Unless I am misunderstanding your last comment.

Comment: yeah, take a view at arr. It can give you this distribution in each small image segment

Comment: Ok, I will check it tomorrow, I am not on my computer with the mathematica license right now.  A separate question - why do you prefer ColorQuantize instead of the way I used which is ColorSeparate, then Binarize, then pseudo color back so that all the green or red is equal. Seems that ColorQuantize leaves more room for noise? By the way, if it's not obvious, I'm completely new to Mathematica, so I appreciate your patience and help.

Comment: Oh, this do will help some times. But I think they're almost the same? at least in this case?

Comment: ok thanks, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.  I'm still working to understand your code (difficult when I can't run it from this computer). But you're saying that if I run everything up to the "mat=total", it will provide a distribution of each small segment. Don't I need a DominatColor function somewhere in there?

Comment: only at the beginning when I separate those colors.

Comment: please accept and upvote my post~ as you can see, I'm still low in reputation......

Comment: I did but since Im still new it says it won't be publicly displayed until I get 15 reputation points